# How to cluster or group days and write it to a .csv file in R?

Tags: r, csv, grouping

I have this enormous df with measurements over 10 days. Now I need to get variances and repeatabilities for the entire dataset, single days, and clusters of days. It was rather easy to do it for the entire dataset. For the single days I created the following loop (which worked btw):

```
All_D <- unique(lam$Start_date)
for  (d in 1:10){  
  jaj.d <- All_D[d]
  Days.d <- subset(lam, Start_date == jaj.d)
  jaa <- as.data.frame(as.table(with(Days.d, tapply(CH4, ID, FUN = var))))
  names(jaa) <- c("ID", "within_ani") 
  write.csv(jaa, paste("Day_",jaj.d,".csv",sep = ""),row.names = F)
  }
```

Now I would like to make groups of two days which "walk through" the 10 days, but they have to stay clustered.. So like:

> 2013-09-01 & 2013-09-02, 2013-09-02 & 2013-09-03, 2013-09-03 & 2013-09-04, .. ,
>   2013-09-09 & 2013-09-10

I think it is necessary to create another loop, but (except for the information above) I have no clue where to start.. I also have to group 3 - 9 days, so I'd rather not do it by hand! I have a df which looks as follows:

```
'data.frame':   1420847 obs. of  22 variables:
$ ID     : int  12338 12338 12338 12338 12338 12338 12338 12338 12338 12338 ...
$ CO2       : int  1510 1950 1190 1170 780 870 730 740 680 700 ...
$ CH4       : int  66 77 62 58 34 51 36 43 32 40 ...
$ Start_date: chr  "2013-09-01" "2013-09-01" "2013-09-01" "2013-09-01" ...
```

I am kind of a noob concerning R, and I was hoping someone could give me a nudge in the right direction? I have been struggling with this for a couple of hours and I cannot seem to find a solution on this website or somewhere else on the web. English is not my native language and I find it kind of hard to come up with the right search terms, so it really is not for lack of trying.

If my question is still unclear, let me know and I'll try to adjust it.

**EDIT**

Soooooo, with the help of you guys I came up with this loop:

```
> lam <- df
lam$Start_date <- as.Date(lam$Start_date)
require(data.table)
lam <- as.data.table(lam)                    #transform df to dt
lam[,date1 := c(1, diff(Start_date))]        #assign each date a different number
lam[,date1 := cumsum(date1)]


for (i in 1:10) {                                #loop through each level of date
    lap.i <- split(lam, lam$date1)               #split date1 to get single days 

for (j in 1:(i+1)) {                             #loop through each level of date 
     lap.j <- split(lam, lam$date1)              #split date1 to get the day after i
     }
     for (k in (i+2)) {
          lap.k <- split(lam, lam$date1)         #split date1 to get the day after j
          }
          for (l in 1:(i+3)) {
               lap.l <- split(lam, lam$date1)    #split date1 to get the day after k
               }
lap.i.j.k.l <- rbind(lap[[i]], lap[[j]], lap[[k]], lap[[l]]) #binding the lists together
var.i.j.k.l <- var(lap.i.j.k.l$CH4)              #get the between individual variance for CH4

#get a df with individual variances for CH4
kill <- as.data.frame(c(with(lap.i.j.k.l, tapply(CH4, CowID, FUN = var)), var.i.j.k.l)) 
names(kill) <- c("variance")                     #name columns in df

#write to a .csv file in wd
write.csv(kill, paste("consecutive days_", i, "_", j, "_", k, "_", l, ".csv", sep = ""))
}
```

This does exactly what I want, however, R is not a big fan of a loop inside a loop inside a loop and so on. The loop above is to get tables with the data of 4 consecutive days, I need to go until 9 consecutive days.. Since the loop above is already asking a lot of this computer, I was wondering what is a shorter, easier, more efficient way to accomplish this? Not "if" because I know it exists, Codoremifa already kind of showed me that, it's just that his code did not exactly do what I want, and I can't seem to figure out how it precisely works..

**EDIT 2**
What I am trying to accomplish:

```
   ID      CO2   CH4  dates       date1
 1 12338   1510  66   2013-09-01  1   
 2 12338   1950  77   2013-09-01  1 
 3 12338   1190  62   2013-09-01  1
 4 12338   1170  58   2013-09-02  1
 5 12338   780   34   2013-09-02  1
 6 12338   870   51   2013-09-03  2
 7 12338   1670  66   2013-09-03  2   
 8 12338   1980  77   2013-09-03  2 
 9 12338   1330  62   2013-09-04  2
10 12338   1850  58   2013-09-04  2
11 12338   1640  34   2013-09-05  3
12 12338   590   51   2013-09-05  3
```

And after that lists like:

```
> [1]
ID       var
12338    164077.4
12339    78420.31
12352    91472.76

> [2]
ID       var
12338    33543.16
12339    184467.1
12352    202267.3
```

Which I would like to write to a .csv file

Comment: What exactly are repeatabilities? Also, can you post sample input and output?

Comment: I get the repeatability as follows: between individual variance/(between individual variance + individual variance). It is a manner to determine the variation in measurements taken by a single instrument on the same individual and under the same conditions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what your output needs to look like. This should give you an idea of what to try though. If you can post sample data the I could edit my answer accordingly

```
library(data.table)
# sample data
dt <- data.table(
dates = rep(seq.Date(
    as.Date('01-01-2013','%d-%m-%Y'),
    as.Date('03-01-2013','%d-%m-%Y'),
    by = 'days'
    ),3),
values = rnorm(3,0)
)

# ordering dataset by dates    
setkeyv(dt,'dates')

# assigning each date a unique number
dt[,flag := c(0,diff(dates))]
dt[,flag := cumsum(flag)]
noofdates <- max(dt[,flag])+1

# i is the counter for how many dates need to be clubbed
for ( i in 1:3 )
{
  # creating list to store intermediate data
  grouplist <- vector(mode = "list", length = i)

  # j is the counter for each group of i dates
  for ( j in 1:(noofdates-i+1) )
  {
    # egtting the subset for each group
    dttemp <- dt[flag %in% c(j:(j+i))]

    # storing the variance in a list
    grouplist[[j]] <- dttemp[, list(varvalues = var(values))]
  }

  # combining the list into one data.table
  groupdt <- rbindlist(grouplist)

  #write out
  write.csv(groupdt,paste0('name_',i,"_",j,'.csv'))
}
```

Comment: Do I need to install a package for this? I cannot find the `setkeyv` and also `:=` gives me an error.. I am kind of new to R so a little more clarity would be appreciated. Thank you for trying to help me!

Comment: `library(data.table)` is calling a new package called `data.table`. You will need to run `install.packages('data.table')` so that this gets installed. Once installed, you should be able to run this.

Comment: Ofcourse.. It already says so in your answer.. I scrolled down too fast, so I did not see the first line until now. I'm sorry! Going to try this one now!

Comment: Tried your solution, and it seems to work but still does not give me the output I want.. I gave an example output in the question. I hope I do not bother you too much! Thank you for your time!

Comment: The values in the var column, they don't look like variances on CH4. that aside, if you are able to run the above code and can understand it, then I don't think it should be a problem to adapt this code to work with your dataset.

Comment: You're right, they don't. I just came up with the wrong values. These were for the ratio I calculated earlier, not very clever. I am working on the code! Thanks so much for the nudge in the right direction!

Comment: Yesterday I ran it and it worked fine, however, now I am getting the following error message: Error in `:=`(date1, cut) : 
  := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":="). Check is.data.table(DT) is TRUE. Do you, by any chance, have an idea what it means?

Comment: Hint: "Check is.data.table(DT) is TRUE". You need to call library(data.table) everytiem you start a new R session.

Comment: Thanks, I already did that, only I forgot to convert the df to a dt.. Thank you for your quick reaction!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure what you mean by "grouping days" (what are you trying to do?).

If you just want to access every 2nd, 3rd, etc. day, this is easily accomplished:

```
# create some data
dates <- as.Date(paste0("1990-11-", 1:10))
df <- data.frame(a = sample(10), b = sample(10), date = dates)

# you could, of course, also specify begin and end manually
days.ordered <- sort(df$date)
begin <- days.ordered[1]
end <- tail(days.ordered, n = 1)

seq(begin, end, by='2 days')  # or 3 days, or 4 days
```

But you seem to be looking for a way to split the entire data frame into groups defined by day intervals.

```
# create some data
dates <- as.Date(paste0("1990-11-", rep(1:10, each=3)))
df <- data.frame(id = rep(1:10, each=3), CH4 = 1:30, CO2 = 1:30, date = dates)

# you could, of course, also specify begin and end manually
days.ordered <- sort(df$date)
begin <- days.ordered[1]
end <- tail(days.ordered, n = 1)

by.n <- 2  # adjust
groups <- seq(begin, end + by.n, by=paste(by.n, "days"))

require(plyr)
ddply(df, .(id, cut(date, breaks = groups)), summarize, 
      VarCH4 = var(CH4),
      varCO2 = var(CO2))
```

Comment: I am trying to calculate a `var` for every two clustered days, not accessing these days. Maybe if you take a look at my edit, it becomes more clear? Thank you for taking time to help me!

Comment: Thanks! It seemed to be working until I got to the very last part of your answer. Here I get the error message that "in cut.default(date1, breaks = groups) : 'x' must be numeric". I tried adjusting it (date1 is `chr`) but it failed.. Do you know what might fix this?
The last few days I did not have a pc available with R so I could not try the answers.. Sorry for my late response!

Comment: To answer your first question: I am trying to group all the data of consecutive 2, 3, 4, etc. days.

Comment: Your column 'dates' (Edit 2) is a factor variable (most likely because you read in your data with `read.csv`or `read.table`). Try `df$dates <- as.Date(df$dates)`.